# I need a function for a non-symetric sigmoid curve.(S-curve)

Tags: functions, exponential-function, curves

I have some "pre-digested" data, that has been described as a sum of sigmoid functions.

Ascending sigmoids range from 0 to 1. Descending sigmoids range from 0 to -1.
Each sigmoid is characterised by 3 parameters (p,q,r), where r is the gradient at the inflection point (p,q):   $-\infty \lt x \lt \infty$. Note, this is non-symetrical in that the inflection does not occur at y = 0.5, but at y = q.

I can see why they have done this as it allows an easy first order representation of the data.
Trouble is they have not specified the function used for the sigmoid.

So I am looking for a differentiable function for a sigmoid expressed in terms of p,q,r.

I suspect this will be a relatively simple equation, but all the sigmoids I've tried to refactor get really complicated, or can only be done peicewise.

I think there will be multiple solutions, so the cigar goes to the simplest one that satisfies the requirements.

Is anyone familiar with the function I'm looking for?

Comment: What do you mean, precisely, with the inflection point? If you mean that it's the point in the graph where the slope of the graph is the greatest (either positive or negative), and you have defined that the sigmoid function is always between 0 and 1 or 0 and -1; doesn't this mean that the inflection point should pretty much always have $y$-coordinate equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ or $-\frac{1}{2}$ ? Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @MattiP. maybe I'm using the wrong term, but that is the point I mean't. Where the 2nd deriviative = 0. Your comment got truncated

Comment: Well, I won't pretend that this is an answer, but here's something to play with: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8nikbmsixw

You can see that if you have $S(x)$ as the sigmoid function, and instead of $y=S(x)$, you take $y=S(k\cdot(x-a))$ then you'll see that the inflection point is at $\left(a,  \frac{1}{2} \right)$ and the slope at the inflection point is $k/4$. Play with those parameters to see what happens. Is there some other modification that you need?

Comment: @MattiP.   OK, can read the comments now. A symetrical S-curve will have y=.5 at the inflection but a non-symetric one wont. I require an equation where the y-value at the point of inflection is specified, eg an inflection at (70,0.7)

Comment: If you need a non-symmetric function, I think we're going to have to stretch the definition of a sigmoid curve. Perhaps what you need is **not** of the form
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-g(x)}}
$$
for some function $g(x)$. I think we're going to have to get creative with this ...

Comment: What I'm after still fits the wiki definition, "A sigmoid function is a bounded, differentiable, real function that is defined for all real input values and has a non-negative derivative at each point and exactly one inflection point."